# Perl Version 5.16.3 download

Tags: perl

Needed to download Perl 5.16.3 32 bit windows edition but unable to find the same. Can someone please suggest from where i can download this.

Apology if this is not the right forum to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the Strawberry Perl releases [here](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html).

ActivePerl 5.16 is too old, so it's only availabe in the Business and Enterprise edition, details [here](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Advanced users can compile Perl from the source code. [This page](http://www.cpan.org/src/README.html) seems to list the version you need.

Comment: Thanks @choroba. It helped me. While compiling I am getting "Program too big to fit in memory". Command used "Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl". Machine is 32 bit Win 2008. I want to generate the win 32 compatible 5.16.3 perl

Comment: Compiling? What's wrong with Strawberry? It comes with a complete toolchain, ready to go.